# How to swap character model in PSX game?

Tags: mesh, modding, playstation1

I would like to know how I can change the 3D model of a PSX ROM running on an emulator.

For example, in Silent Hill 1, I would love to play as other characters by simply replacing the 3D models.

How can I do this?